# Create vars with another dict var

Tags: ansible

Into a "/vars/main.yml" file to a role, I'm trying to create a variable with another value of dict var, like this :

```
livrables_list_files:
  - file: "myfile.zip"
    dest: "/tmp/mynewfile.zip"

zip_app: "{{ livrables_list_files.dest }}"
```

But my playbook result return `The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'dest'`

I would like to have a var like :

```
zip_app: "/tmp/mynewfile.zip"
```

Is it possible to access to this var ? Even with json syntax may be OK in my case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'dest. Is it possible to access this var ?"*

A: Yes. It's possible. The problem is the dash in front of the first item which makes the variable `livrables_list_files` a **list**. To reference the attribute `dest` of the first item in the list an index is needed. For example

```
zip_app: "{{ livrables_list_files.0.dest }}"
```

If you remove the dash

```
livrables_list_files:
  file: "myfile.zip"
  dest: "/tmp/mynewfile.zip"
```

it will be possible to reference the attribute `dest` of the **dictionary** `livrables_list_files`

```
zip_app: "{{ livrables_list_files.dest }}"
```